# Android MVVM DataModel with Context

Tags: android, mvvm

I am trying to learn & implement MVVM with databinding in my app. But I am facing difficulties in understanding/deciding few things.

I have one header view in my app which I need to use in multiple activities, so I basically created this

```
view_header.xml
HeaderViewModel.java (implements java.util.Observer)
HeaderDataModel.java (extends java.util.Observable)
```

where `HeaderViewModel` is bound with `view_header.xml`.
Now I include the `view_header.xml` in `activity_xyz.xml` & set ViewModel of Header View from that `XyzActivity` like this,

```
xyzViewBinding.setHeaderVm(new HeaderViewModel(new HeaderDataModel(mContext)));
```

Now I have questions based on this:

1) As `HeaderDataModel` needs context to work with `SharedPreference` & `BroadcastReceiver`, I initialize it inside the `XyzActivity` instead of `HeaderViewModel`- Is this correct approach?

2) I had to rely on broadcast receiver to update my header view, so I registered it inside the constructor of `HeaderDataMode`. Now as my `HeaderDataModel` is `Observable`, whenever I receive broadcast, I call `notifyObservers()` so that the observer(HeaderViewModel) detects it & updates it view.- Is this correct approach?

3) as I register receiver in constructor of HeaderDataModel, I created onDestroy() method inside data model where I unregister it & I call this onDestroy from XyzActivity’s onDestroy().- Is this correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

1. As HeaderDataModel needs context to work with SharedPreference & BroadcastReceiver, I initialize it inside the XyzActivity instead of HeaderViewModel- Is this correct approach? - **No, It is wrong. You must initialize it in HeaderDataModel so later on if you want to update HeaderDataModel, you can easily do it.**
2. I had to rely on broadcast receiver to update my header view, so I registered it inside the constructor of HeaderDataMode. Now as my HeaderDataModel is Observable, whenever I receive broadcast, I call notifyObservers() so that the observer(HeaderViewModel) detects it & updates it view.- Is this correct approach? - **Yes as i told it in first point.**
3. as I register receiver in constructor of HeaderDataModel, I created onDestroy() method inside data model where I unregister it & I call this onDestroy from XyzActivity’s onDestroy().- Is this correct approach? - **Yes. make public ondestroy() method in HeaderDataModel class.**

Comment: I guess u mean I must initialize it inside HeaderViewModel. but as HeaderDataModel constructor needs Context, in order to initialize it from ViewModel, I'll need context. so isn't this against principal that ViewModel shouldn't reference any android APIs or classes? That's why I initialized it inside Activity & passing it to ViewModel in constructor so that ViewModel can modify it/use it.